# How do I run the same Robot Framework test against different URLs in one test run?

Tags: automation, robotframework

I've created some Robot Framework tests for my company that check some basic UI functions. Pretty simple stuff. However, we have several different nodes of our sites that these tests need to run against. The test steps will all be identical, but the URLs will change for each node. I need this to happen automatically, without having to change the run parameters each time. It runs the test in one node, then automatically goes to the next node. I've got it working like you see below, but I know there has to be a more elegant way to get this done. Does anybody have any ideas on how I can make this better?

I have looked into the data driven part before, but for the life of me, I can't get how to parameterize the URL in a Setup to where, when the test completes, it just moves onto the next node and keeps going. I'm really at a loss here.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Initial Test on Gibson nodes
Library             Zoomba.GUILibrary
Resource            ../../Pages/resource.robot
Suite Teardown      Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${browser}          chrome
${url1}              https://(URL ONE)/home
${url2}              https://(URL TWO)/home

*** Keywords ***
Setup ONE
     [Arguments]    ${url1}=https://(URL ONE)/home  ${browser}=${browser}
     Open Browser   ${url1}  browser=${browser}  options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
     Maximize Browser Window
     Set Selenium Speed    0.3s
     
Setup TWO
     [Arguments]    ${url2}=https://(URL TWO)/home  ${browser}=${browser}
     Open Browser   ${url2}  browser=${browser}  options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
     Maximize Browser Window
     Set Selenium Speed    0.3s
     

*** Test Cases ***
TC 001 Node ONE
    Setup ONE
    Display Node
    Sign In
    Check Menu Tabs

TC 002 Node TWO
    Setup TWO
    Display Node
    Sign In
    Check Menu Tabs
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the usage of [Test templates](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates). This would enable you to write the test logic as a keyword, that would serve as a template for the test cases. Then you can run this template against various parameters.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    Test Template Keyword

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}          chrome
${URL1}              https://(URL ONE)/home
${URL2}              https://(URL TWO)/home
${URL3}              https://(URL 2TWO)/home
${URL4}              https://(URL 3TWO)/home

*** Keywords ***
Setup <ANY>
     [Arguments]    ${url}  ${browser}=${BROWSER}
     # Open Browser   ${url}  browser=${browser}  options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
     # Maximize Browser Window
     # Set Selenium Speed    0.3s
     Log Many    ${url}    ${browser}
     
Display Node
    No Operation

Sign In
    No Operation
    
Check Menu Tabs
    No Operation
    
Test Template Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${url}  ${browser}=${BROWSER}
    Setup <ANY>    ${url}  ${browser}
    Display Node
    Sign In
    Check Menu Tabs
     

*** Test Cases ***
TC 001 Node ONE
    ${URL1}

TC 002 Node TWO
    ${URL2}    Firefox
    
TC 003 Node THREE
    ${URL3}
    
TC 004 Node FOUR
    ${URL4}
```

You can choose to have individual test cases for each input parameter set, this is what is shown above. Or you can have a single test case that independently runs each parameter set. If any iteration fails the whole test case will be marked as failed but regardless of the failures the template with all parameter set will be executed.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Name of single test case
    ${URL1}
    ${URL2}    Firefox
    ${URL3}
    ${URL4}
```

Comment: it worked! You really saved me here, thank you so much!

Comment: @JustinHooks Glad to hear. If it really helped consider accepting the answer (tick mark). :)